# Changed frame returns to default when view disappears and appears again

Tags: ios, objective-c, frame

I have a tab bar application using storyboard and in one view, I change the frame of a UIButton animated within a method. The thing is that the method is perfectly continuing while another tab bar item is presented (so the view controller is not dismissed but only disappeared) but when the first view appears again, the button whose frame had changed is in the default position again, as I set it in interface builder.
Does anybody know if there's an easy way to prevent this behaviour and keep the current frames when a view disappears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Auto Layout? (Storyboard > Utilities (right panel) > File Inspector - Has a Use Auto Layout checkbox). If so, try to uncheck it. If it works right, then you need to change the `Layout Constrains`, not the `frame`.
Parameters like `frame` and `center` are ignored under Auto Layout. Instead, constrains have a parameter called `constant` that can be changed and animated.

Comment: @fabf98dev Sure thing. Run into this myself. Layout Constrains can be created in Interface Builder and Control+Drag as property into the code. You can then change the myConstrain.constant easily.